# Unexpected behaviour of NOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```sql
CREATE TABLE t 
(
    a VARCHAR(50),
    b VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO t (a) VALUES (null);
INSERT INTO t (a) VALUES ('v');
INSERT INTO t (b) VALUES ('v');
INSERT INTO t (a, b) VALUES ('v', 'v');
INSERT INTO t (a, b) VALUES ('v', 'x');

SELECT
    a, b,
    CASE 
        WHEN (a = b OR (a IS NULL AND b IS NULL))  
            THEN 'true' 
            ELSE 'false' 
    END "nullSafeEqual",
    CASE 
        WHEN NOT (a = b OR (a IS NULL AND b IS NULL))  
            THEN 'true' 
            ELSE 'false' 
    END "NotNullSafeEqual"
FROM
    t
```

[image]

I expected the second formula to be the `NOT` the first formula, but this is not the case.

What is happening here?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0):

Boolean expressions may return one of three values: `true` or `false` or `null`.

The boolean expression:

```
a=b or (a is null and b is null)
```

does not return always `true` or `false`.

There is a case that it returns `null` when just one of `a` or `b` is `null`.

In this case `a=b` returns `null` (because any comparison to `null` with the operator `=` returns `null`) and `a is null and b is null` returns `false`, so the final result is equivalent to `null or false` and that evaluates to `null`.

Similarly, for the evaluation of:

```
not (a=b or (a is null and b is null))
```

the result is `not null` which is `null`.

In both cases the `when` branches of the `CASE` expressions will fail because the result is **not** `true` (it is `null`) and end up to the `else` branches which return the string `'false'` (not because the boolean expressions are `false` but because they are not `true`, since they are `null`).

Comment: The three values in 3VL are rather true, false, and unknown. Null denotes the absence of a value, which is still something else.

Comment: @TT. The *unknown* value of a boolean expression is returned as `null`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I understand, (and tried best to answer my question)

Answer (score 0):

This result comes from the fact that the boolean expression contains a comparison with null values which results neither in `TRUE` nor in `FALSE` but `UNKNOWN`(`NULL`).

Read [this](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/how-to-get-nulls-horribly-wrong-in-sql-server/#ninth) or [this](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/18/why-null-never-compares-false-to-anything-in-sql/)("NULL is not unequal to anything").

So you shouldn't use the `NOT` operator here to avoid the trap.

Answer (score -1):

the result of comparisons with '=' can be `True`,`False` or `NULL` (or `unknown`).

`NULL=1` is   `NULL` which evaluates to `falsy` (in an WHEN statement)

`NOT (NULL=1)` is also `NULL`, which surprises me.

```sql
select 
   case when 1=2 or null = 1 then 'true' else 'false' end "false or unkown" -- false 
 , case when 1=1 or null = 1 then 'true' else 'false' end "true  or unkown" -- true
 , case when        null = 1 then 'true' else 'false' end "         unkown" -- false
 , case when not    null = 1 then 'true' else 'false' end "not      unkown" -- false
```

Comment: (1) the result of comparisons with '=' is never 'unknown' because there is no such value, (2) NULL does not evaluate to *falsy* (or anything like false). When there is something like `CASE WHEN NULL THEN ... ELSE ...` the return value is what is returned by the ELSE branch because the result of the WHEN branch is not TRUE (although this does not mean that it is FALSE).